# Issues with sharing partitions using NFS

Tags: files, nfs, file-sharing

We have 3 servers: Server1, Server2 and Server3, all in the same network.
On Server2 I'm sharing a partition, say `/part1`, to Server 3 using **NFS**.
Here's the `/etc/exports` on Server2:
`/part1 Server3(rw)`

and here's the `/etc/fstab` from Server3:

```
Server2:/part1 /part1  nfs defaults    0 0
```

This is working absolutely fine.

Then I shared a partition `/part2` on Server1 to Server2 and Server3 with the condition that this has to be a sub-directory of `/part1`.
The `/etc/exports` on Server1:

```
/part2 Server2(rw) Server3(rw)
```

and the `/etc/fstab` from Server2:

```
Server1:/part2 /part1/part2  nfs defaults    0 0
```

With this configuration `/part2` is perfectly accessible to Server2 but **not to Server3**.
Am I missing anything?

If its of any significance, `/part2` is formatted as **ocfs2**. Other partitions are **ext3** and all servers are running **Oracle Linux 5**.

Comment: so how do `server2` and `server3` differ?

Comment: In what sense? I'm not sure I get your question.

Comment: since it's working on `server2` and not working on `server3`, they might have different configurations (you only gave the config for `server2`)

Comment: I haven't changed anything in `Server3`. It's `fstab` still has the same settings that I already mentioned.

Comment: you haven't told use what the `fstab` on `Server3` is at all. and btw, i'm not sure it is entirely clear which server is exporting to where and how. probably you should try making a diagram of what you expect to be visible on each server.